# How we can see the newest unanswered questions?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, sorting, newest-questions

We can see the newest and unanswered questions separately. How can we see the newest unanswered questions? In the unanswered questions link it shows unanswered questions in the order of upvotes to the questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is difference between searching for question which are unanswered(no answers at all) and questions with no accepted answers along with newest sort...
You can take advantage of Advance Search tips here:

- Searching for question with no answer at all
      [answers:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers:0)
- Searching for questions having answers but with no accepted answer
     [hasaccepted:no](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted:no) or  as @him056 said [Unanswered tab](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest)

Comment: is there a tutorial for the advanced search? how can I learn them?

Comment: @user689 yes [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Answer (score 5):

Go to the [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/) tab -> select the [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) tab. Here you will the newest questions with **no upvoted answers**. That means it includes those questions which have answer(s) with zero score.