# Filter option for Unanswered

Tags: feature-request, answers, bounties, hot-questions, unanswered-questions

When you are looking at recent questions, your filter options are *bountied*, *hot*, *week*, and *month* (plus some site-specific ones).

It seems to me the only reason someone would be browsing questions is if they're looking for ones to answer. Showing all the most recent questions makes sense, as does showing the ones with active bounties. I can't understand who would ever want to look at the top questions for the last week/month other than Stack Exchange employees or moderators.

But it seems it's missing the most obvious and useful tab, **Unanswered**.

Unanswered would greatly help people whose questions got ignored and didn't get answered in the first few hours (and are now buried), as well as people looking to answer questions, without having to sift through all the questions on the default tab which have already been answered, or trying to answer as fast as possible on new questions before someone else does.

It would be a win-win. I would appreciate it both as an asker whose questions often go unanswered, and as a poster who would like finding questions to answer to be easier.

Comment: If you go to the /questions page unanswered is an option. Are you looking at the home page? That is actually the activity page  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How we can see the newest unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226387/how-we-can-see-the-newest-unanswered-questions)

Comment: I suppose that is what I want, so I guess now I wonder what the point of the homepage is at all, if it's just a worse question page.